# Lightning Screen Flow: Can you control what happens when a user "Closes" the screen flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

We have project that requires us to call an API in the middle of a screen flow and then call the same api at the end of the flow. The issue I'm concerned with is if a user closes the flow in the middle of guided process (i.e. clicks the 'x' button ), and we are not able to make the final api call to conclude the process.

**Is there a way to handle the flow when a user clicks 'x' on a screen flow?**

Comment: nothing clean to my knowledge.  you could use a custom object to track this and monitor for ones that are not completed, and then do (Something..) fwiw i think  this is also a flaming hole in using flows to [activate and deactivate session-based permission sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_session_activate_flow.htm&type=5) assuming you only want the user to have access to these permissions while running the flow.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I'm going to have to go the route of putting this flow in to a lighting web component.

Comment: @gorav I think you can do this with local actions...https://rajvakati.com/2018/12/02/flow-local-actions-using-lightning-components/

Comment: that would be interesting - if you find a solution using local actions that handles the event where a user closes out the flow, please share!!